# How would I go about getting the title, date, and url of the last ten blog posts from multiple sites?

Tags: php, javascript, rss

I need to read multiple rss feeds from different blogs and get just the title, date, and url for the last 10 posts of each site, and then format those lists however I like.

I'm working on creating a buzz type website. Somewhat like [affbuzz.com](http://www.affbuzz.com).

Please let me know the easiest and cleanest way of doing this, either in php, or jquery etc... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate the feeds. Either use [SimplePie](http://simplepie.org/) or [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html). If you are after a PopURLs clone, [SimplePie has a tutorial for this as well](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_replicate_popurls). An alternative would be to use [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=overview)

Answer (score 1):

Have a RSS feed reader showing first ten items from each feed if you don't wish to store the items. For a buzz type site, I don't feel you need to store them at your end.